# How to search new Docs template gallery?

Tags: google-docs

So the general [Google Template Gallery is going away](https://drive.google.com/templates?ddrp=1#), apparently to be replaced by more specific galleries, such as the one for [Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/). Problem is, I can't figure out how to search for existing templates in the new Docs gallery. Googling the answer yielded nothing other than dark warnings about the current Template Gallery's expiring lease on life. How do I search the new Docs Gallery?